# Making a Circular Dial like menu

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, native

Am currently working on a circular dial like menu like one below, where user can scroll to select an option. May I get any UI ideas for achieving this in native Android development.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AbsoluteLayout is deprecated.

However, you are lucky:
there is a similar open source project on github:
https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView

Answer (score 1):

Good Question,

You can use "**AbsoluteLayout**" for this type of UI.

Black Image for Dialer and , Than small images for numbers.

Thank you,